# Netlogo: How can I set timer counting for multiple turtles at once?

Tags: timer, counter, netlogo

How can I set timer counting for multiple turtles at once? Below is the sample syntax. With this syntax, if two turtles are present, timer counting will be cumulatively counted by 2 for each tick. Example: 2, 4, 6, 8, ..., another example: If 3 turtles are present, 3, 6, 9, ..., cumulative counting is done for each tick. The decrement timer also has the same problem. In this model, a turtle infinitely born at the origin patch (0 0), and after a certain period of time, the turtles die one by one. This problem occurred even if there were multiple patches, too. I probably need your advice. Thank you.

```
    ask (turtles-on patch 0 0)
  [
    set count-up count-up + 1
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused about the difference between a global variable and a turtle owned variable. If you have multiple turtles being created at different times, then you probably want each to have its own timer (so that the value can be different for different turtles). If all you want is a global variable to increase or decrease each tick, then don't put it in an `ask` statement. Just say something like 'set counter counter + 1`.

Here is a complete model that should help you to understand what's going on in your code.

```
globals [num-turtles counter ave-count-up]
turtles-own [count-up]

to setup
  clear-all
  set num-turtles 5
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  set counter counter + 1
  if count turtles < num-turtles
  [ ask patch 0 0
    [ sprout 1
      [ set count-up 0 ]
    ]
  ]
  ask (turtles-on patch 0 0)
  [ set count-up count-up + 1
    show count-up
  ]
  type "Current value of counter is " print counter
  type "Number of turtles: " print count turtles
  type "Total of all turtle counters: " print sum [count-up] of turtles
  set ave-count-up mean [count-up] of turtles
  tick
end
```

Comment: Your assertion is incorrect, BehaviorSpace can record whatever it is told to record in the box about measures to record - not just global variables. But it is awkward to record the values for all the individual turtles because there are many values to record and the number of values changes. Maybe you can get away with max, min, mean and standard deviation for example? If not, you can still tell BehaviorSpace to record all the values, but you will need to do some processing of the csv file.

Comment: That is also not true. Create your monitor to display `mean [count-up] of turtles`. Nevertheless, I will edit the program above to show you how to do what you want as a global variable.

Comment: I suspect you put `tick` inside an `ask turtles [ ]`, which you should not do. If you look at my code above, you will see that `tick` is the last command before `end` in the `go` procedure and that it is not inside any other block of code. Have you actually done the tutorials on the NetLogo website? If not, I suggest you do as they will help you with some basic concepts, NetLogo is not the same as other languages.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have done the tutorial, but I did not understand it much. My experiences are Fortran, C, but Netlogo is my first time. My area is still not famous for Netlogo. I have learned a lot on this website. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I thought you might be a programmer - it can be difficult for someone who already has coding experience to learn NetLogo initially because it thinks in a different way than other languages. One big difference is what is referred to as 'context' who is doing the operation (observer, turtle, patch, link). Fortran/C really only have the equivalent of the observer - the controller of the overall program. NetLogo is much more bottom up. Once you understand how and why my code works (particularly switching between observer and turtle with `ask`), try the tutorial again.